# Why wxWidgets never calls delete after calling new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, wxwidgets

I'm looking at wxWidgets hello world and example from: http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm and http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hworld2.txt and
http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/

and other links..

I noticed they have:

```
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}
```

and

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
       : wxFrame(NULL, -1, title, pos, size)
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;

    menuFile->Append( ID_About, _("&About...") );
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append( ID_Quit, _("E&xit") );

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, _("&File") );

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText( _("Welcome to wxWidgets!") );
}
```

Not a single one of these snippets, tutorials, links use delete!
How can this be? Why don't they delete a single thing?

Is there something they're doing that I just don't see? Maybe somehow overriding "new" and having it automatically delete somehow?

What is the trick?

Comment: They're clearly passing those instances to other functions (who based on their names are now the ones responsible for the objects in question.)  Deleting them after the fact would leave those other functions unhappy, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are passed each time to some function, which consumes the objects and dispose them at will.

Answer (score 4):

wxWidgets takes ownership of most of the objects you create and the few exceptions are explicitly mentioned in the documentation. In particular, windows are owned by their parent window, menu items are owned by the menu containing them and the menus themselves are owned by the menu bar, and the sizers are owned by the window they are associated with. As a special case, the top level windows are "self-owned" i.e. they are destroyed when the corresponding on screen window is closed.

Notice that all this works as long as wxWidgets "knows" about your objects. If you create a menu and don't attach it to the menu bar, you *are* responsible for deleting it, otherwise you'd get a memory leak.